# Extract uploaded zip file?

Tags: php, file-upload, zip

I have made a form where a file is uploaded:

```
<form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="file" type="file">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Now I'm not sure how to write `upload.php`. I generally expect a .zip file to be uploaded. This file should then be extracted in some temporary directory, and some certain logic should then be performed for each file in it. How do I do that in the most elegant way? It feels like I shouldn't have to move it. Can't I just extract the .zip-file directly in the tmp directory in which PHP puts its uploaded files?

Answer (score 0):

Extract Zip File

```
if(mkdir('temp', 0777, true)){ //create temp dir
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    if ($zip->open('file.zip') === TRUE) {
      $zip->extractTo('temp/');
      zip->close();
    }
}
```

Comment: That part looks good. However, it doesn't really feel good to extract it in a folder in the same directory as `uploads.php`. I guess what I'm wondering is if there's any more elegant way to get a temporary directory to put stuff in.

Comment: I know you can just create a directory, though I'm wondering if there's a built in mechanism for this, kind of like the uploads tmp directory.